# SSH Client that has a GUI directory tree whose view synchronizes with current dir in Terminal?

Tags: user-interface, ssh, winscp

I am looking for an SSH client with the following features:

1. A terminal/shell (text-only) interface.
2. A GUI with directory tree (like windows explorer).
3. **The ability to keep these views in sync**-- ie. when you enter the command `cd ..` in the terminal, the directory tree GUI will update its view, and navigate up one directory.

I know that several SSH clients exist with *1* and *2*, such as [winscp](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/introduction). However, I have never seen *3* in it or other clients.

Does anyone know of a SSH client with this ability to synchronize the view between the terminal session and the GUI?

Comment: Belongs to http://superuser.com/

Comment: Good Point! For users (like me) that are not sure where to ask their question, here is the [directory of Q&A sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites). I will be sure to refer to this in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WinSCP does do this.

If you use the SCP method (rather than FTP or SFTP) when connecting, you can open a terminal (from *Commands > Open Terminal*) and `cd` to your heart's content. When you close the terminal, the file view changes to where you left it.

Ok so its not instant... but all you have to do is close the terminal, see the new GUI, reopen with a shortcut (<kbd>CTRL+T</kbd>) and you have what you're looking for.

Comment: WinSCP can do this even with SFTP and FTP protocol, not only SCP.